# How to get javascript stack trace in Internet Explorer. e.stack returns "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, exception, stack-trace

I tried the following code

```
try {
  alertt("dddd");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

It results stack trace in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. But it returns **undefined** in Internet Explorer.

Is there any method to get stack trace in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? as you can read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh699850(v=vs.94).aspx it's supported from IE 10

Comment: @BeNdErR Thanks, I am using IE9. Let me update and check it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Syntax :

```
errorObj = new Error()
errorObj = new Error([number])
errorObj = new Error([number[, description]])
```

Parameters explain :

errorObj

```
Required. The variable name to which the Error object is assigned. The variable assignment is omitted when you create the error using a throw statement.
```

number

```
Optional. Numeric value assigned to an error. Zero if omitted.
```

description

```
Optional. Brief string that describes an error. Empty string if omitted.
```

Example

```
function checkInput(x) {
    try
    {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(x))) {
            throw new Error("Input is not a number.");
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        document.write(e.description);
    }
}

checkInput("not a number");
```

Note : Whenever a run-time error occurs, an instance of the Error object is created to describe the error. This instance has two intrinsic properties that contain the description of the `error (description property)` and the `error number (number property)`. For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/1dk3k160%28v=vs.94%29.aspx.

An error number is a 32-bit value. The upper 16-bit word is the facility code, while the lower word is the actual error code.

Comment: Is it possible to get line number?

Comment: It will return two instance such as error and error number @Sajith

Comment: I'm not sure about line number. IF my above post help you, please accept my post @Sajith

Answer (score 2):

Your code definitely works in IE11; I've just tried it. I believe it should also work in at least IE10.

You might also be interested in `console.trace` which gives you a stack trace. That's definitely new in IE11, but that just makes it another good reason to upgrade -- the dev tools in IE11 are orders of magnitude better than before.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `e.description` as mentionned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dww52sbt%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) documentation :